# Select All On Focus of GWT SuggestBox

Tags: gwt, selectall, gwt-widgets, suggestbox

I've been searching and searching and can't find a usable example of selecting all text within a GWT SuggestBox widget on focus. I understand you have to attach a focusListener to the widget, but then what? Can someone provide a working example of this?

Comment: Not sure what you need. Do you want the text highlighted on focus?

Comment: @Jai: Yep. That's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since every example I'd found online was using deprecated code (addFocusListener method), I ended up figuring this one out using the addFocusHandler method instead.

Here's how it was done:

```
    mySuggestBox.getTextBox().addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
            mySuggestBox.getTextBox().selectAll();
        }
    });
```

Comment: getTextBox() is depreciated in favour of getValueBox()

Comment: use scheduler for selecting all on focus event: Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand () {
         public void execute () {
          mySuggestBox.getValueBox().selectAll();
         }
     });

Answer (score 0):

I simply applied  "addFocusListener" to the "TextBox" inside the SuggestBox in the creation of the SuggestBox (where the TextBox itself is reachable as you need it for the creation of the SuggestBox). I guess that in a way it's more logical this way.